# Getting JSON data on server side with Grails

Tags: json, grails, groovy

Once I post JSON data to a url in Grails, how can I get access to that data inside of the controller?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Grails automatically parses/unmarshals the JSON and you can access it via `request.JSON` in your controller. The object returned is of type [`JSONObject`](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.1/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/json/JSONObject.html) and thus allows map-style access to the properties. You can also directly use this JSONObject for data binding:

```
def jsonObject = request.JSON
def instance = new YourDomainClass(jsonObject)
```

Comment: could you explain what am I missing with the same approach (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067379/grails-initiating-domain-class-using-json)

Comment: If you don't have a domain class (i.e.the json its input data only), is there any way to parse the jsonObject? Obviously one can do def x = jsonOblect.xxx, but how to you iterate over collections in the bowels of the json?

Answer (score 6):

Check out the JSON classes in Grails:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/json/package-frame.html

For example, here's how I iterate over a list of JSON records in a parameter called 'update':

```
    def updates = new org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray(params.updates)
    for (item in updates) {
                    def p = new Product()
        p.quantity = item.quantity
        p.amount = item.amount
        p = salesService.saveProductSales(p)

    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Are there any other variables/ways of getting posted data other than params? That's what's really causing me the most pain.

Comment: You know what, I found out that I wasn't posting the json, that's why it never appeared in params. So, your solution works out just fine. Thanks again!