# Grails - Initiating domain class using JSON

Tags: json, grails, web, request, grails-domain-class

I have this simple domain class:

```
class Settings {
static constraints = {
    uid(nullable: false, unique: true)
    person()
}

String uid
Map person
}
```

and a web UI that update the data using a json request:

```
{"uid":1234 , person:{"first_name" : "jhon" , "last_name" : "doe"}}
```

in the controller code:

```
def json = request.JSON;
def s = new Settings(json);
```

it seems that **s.uid** is being set however the **s.person** Map remains empty.
What am I missing?

Comment: this is probably a Grails bug http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9220?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following in your controller:

```
def json = request.JSON;
def s = new Settings(json);
s.person = json.person;
```

it's ugly, but the data binding doesn't seem to handle nested json

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... this is odd, I will be  
stubborn and continue the search for a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want that to work you need to convert your structure to this:

```
{"uid":1234 , "person.first_name": "jhon" , "person.last_name": "doe"}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however the UI JSON is a given and cannot be changed. I'm sure there is a smoother solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you add this line before instantiating Settings, it will bind recursively.

```
JSON.use('deep')
```