# Grails : How to access the params coming as JSON format

Tags: json, grails, groovy

from PHP application there is call to grails controller which sends data in JSON format.

when i println the params

```
println params
```

which prints

```
[{"courseCategory":null,"courseId":null,"show":null,
    "rows":6,"trainers":null,"courses":null,"cities":null,
    "fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"pageType":"HOME","deal":null}:,   
    action:getTrainingsAsJson, 
    controller:publicTraining]
```

when i do

```
println  params.rows
println params.pageType
```

which prints `null`

i tried

```
  def jsonObject = request.JSON  // prints [:]
```

I have also tried with `JsonSlurper`

```
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText(params)
```

which gives error

```
No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap)
```

how to convert it to retrieve the param values?

or is there any way to convert it to map so that i can easily access the parameters?

Comment: What do you see with `println params.dump()`?

Comment: The println statement above shows invalid JSON, are you sure that's what you get?

Comment: @dbrin This is a little late, but for posterity: it's actually showing the `params` map that Grails has constructed out of the request parameters. Because monda's JSON was not sent as a parameter, Grails didn't have a name to assign to the JSON and instead it as the key to a map entry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it is a POST request then the JSON can be retrieved from `request` as

```
request.JSON
request.JSON.courseCategory
```

etc

What is see from the request the values are sent `null` from the client. Verify the payload.

Answer (score 7):

```
[{"courseCategory":null,...,"deal":null}:, action:getTrainingsAsJson,  controller:publicTraining]
```

It looks like you are sending your data without key, like

```
data: JSON.stringify({"courseCategory":null,...,"deal":null}),
```

send it with some key like

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '${g.createLink(action: 'asd')}',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: "sendData=" + JSON.stringify({"courseCategory":null,"courseId":null,"show":null, "rows":6,"trainers":null,"courses":null,"cities":null, "fromDate":null,"toDate":null,"pageType":"HOME","deal":null}),
    success: function (data) {
        console.debug(data);
    }
});
```

and then get value like

```
def data = JSON.parse(params.sendData)
def rows = data.rows
```

Try this..,.

Comment: This helped me out lo these many years later! I'm building a Zendesk App and I couldn't specify the `contentType` on the sending end because it would cause the Zendesk framework to send an "OPTIONS" header, which Grails 2.2.0 doesn't map properly. So, Grails couldn't automatically unmarshall the JSON params. Simply making my data into an actual parameter works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone is running into an issue with calling `request.JSON` and receiving null -- be sure that you explicitly set the `dataType` and `contentType`, and send the data as JSON.  For example, using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: yourURL,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JsonSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html). As you'll see, you first need to parse the JSON file and then access all the fields from JSON in property access notation.

Comment: Can u explain with above example

Comment: Updated my question. plz have a look

Answer (score -1):

Grails automatically parses/unmarshals the JSON and you can access it via request.JSON in your controller. The object returned is of type JSONObject and it allows map-style access to the properties. You can also directly use this JSONObject for data binding

```
def jsonObject = request.JSON
def instance = new YourDomainClass(jsonObject)
```

Comment: What if i was updating single instance.

Comment: like ```myInstance.properties = jsonObject```

Comment: it doesn't get null value

Comment: This answer is exactly copied and pasted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3034436/1291122 It would be more ethical to atleast give credits to the author of this answer if you are copying and pasting as it is.

Answer (score -2):

def jsonObject = request.JSON def instance = new YourDomainClass(jsonObject)/extensions/default{"sitekey": "your_site_key", "theme": "light"}.